# Echo no muestra una fecha al usar echo

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Hola dentro de mi tabla trato de mostrar en una tabla el valor "fechaalta" de una base en SQL server y su estructura es esta: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al capturar el valor como con cualquier otro de la misma tabla y tratar de imrimirlo se desconfigura toda mi tabla lo que no me pasa con ningun otro valor

```
$fecha_alta= $usuario['fechaalta'];
echo $fecha_alta;
```

el valor dentro de la tabla se ve de la diguiente manera 2018-04-04 es algun tipo de desconfiguracion o falta de formato? 
de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: No es ninguna *desconfiguración*, es el formato por defecto que adquiere la fecha, el cual es `YYYY-MM-DD`  o lo que es lo mismo: `Año-Mes-Día`.  Si quieres otro formato puedes indicarlo en el `SELECT` o bien hacerlo mediante PHP, por ejemplo: `$fecha_alta= date_format ($usuario['fechaalta'], 'd-m-Y');` Lo que significa cada letra o combinación de letras [está explicado aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Comment: Es importante que agregues en tu pregunta que es lo que esperas recibir, en este caso en que formato necesitas mostrar la fecha, como ya te comentaron no es ninguna desconfiguración, simplemente formatea la fecha con PHP.